# Validating the correct image type with "Active Storage" Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a fresh pair of eyes on this, I am trying to validate the correct image type, I have added the following code to my models book.rb

```html
  private


  def correct_image_type
    if image.attached? && image.content_type.in?(%w(image/jpeg image/png image/jpg))
      errors.add(:image, "Must be a JPG, JPEG or PNG")
    elsif
      image.attached? == false
      errors.add(:image, "must be uploaded")
    end
  end
```

and also

```html
validate :correct_image_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `!`. Also ensure that you purge the invalid attachment when validation fails. This ensures that the invalid attachment doesn't get saved anyway. Here's a quick refactor

```
private

def correct_image_type
  valid_formats = %w(image/jpeg image/png image/jpg)

  if image.attached? && !image.content_type.in?(valid_formats)
     image.purge
     errors.add(:image, "Must be a JPG, JPEG or PNG")
  else
     errors.add(:image, "must be uploaded")
  end
end
```